# Way to shorten this if statement

Tags: ruby, if-statement

How can I shorten this lengthy `if` statement?

```
if command.downcase != 'course analytics' ||
   command.downcase != 'view student averages' ||
   command.downcase != 'report cards' ||
   command.downcase != 'done'
...
end
```

Comment: Did you mean to use == or && there, that condition is always true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Enumerable`'s [`any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F), [`all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F), and [`none?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-none-3F) are your friends for this kind of thing

```
VALID_COMMANDS = [
  'course analytics',
  'view student averages',
  'report cards',
  'done' ]

if VALID_COMMANDS.any? {|s| command.downcase != s }
```

Without seeing the body of your `if`, I suspect you have the sense of your combining operator wrong (as written, your condition will always be true since the string being tested has to be different than one of the values it's tested against)  As stated, you're testing if the command is not equal to any of the strings, I suspect you either want to test that it's equal to one of them or none of them.

```
if VALID_COMMANDS.none? {|s| command.downcase == s }
```

When the test in the block is equality, `include?(foo)` is equivalent to `any? {|x| x == foo }`, so this is the equivalent `none?` test using include:

```
unless VALID_COMMANDS.include? command.downcase
```

Answer (score 4):

```
unless ['course analytics', 'view student averages', 'report cards', 'done'].include? command.downcase
```

Edit:

on a third reading of the original question, I think this is logically equivalent:

```
if true
  ...
end
```

i.e. It will always evaluate to true. Original question needs some clarification.

Comment: This is not equivalent to what OP wrote, it's equivalent to OPs statement if the tests were `==` not `!=`

Answer (score 2):

You can make it very simple. Your code:

```
if # long condition part
  ...
end
```

is equivalent to:

```
...
```

which is the body without the condition. You can get rid of the entire `if` condition.

Answer (score 1):

This is all backwards:

```
if command.downcase != 'course analytics' ||
  command.downcase != 'view student averages' ||
  command.downcase != 'report cards' ||
  command.downcase != 'done'
  ...
end
```

It's very hard to read, and the logic isn't apparent.

Instead of searching for the "not" conditions, look for the positive matches and handle anything that doesn't match using an `else` clause:

```
case command.downcase
when 'course analytics'
  # do the 'course analytics' thing
when 'view student averages' 
  # do the 'view student averages'  thing
when 'report cards'
  # do the 'report cards' thing
when 'done'
  # do the 'done' thing
else
  # do the default thing
end
```

If you are trying to weed-out a bunch of options that have the same action:

```
case command.downcase
when 'course analytics', 'view student averages', 'report cards', 'done'
  ...
else
  # do the default thing
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
['course analytics','view student averages', 'report cards', 'done'].map{ |n| n !=  command.downcase }.reduce(false) {|p,n| p||n}
```

Comment: Explain why this is an appropriate solution. Instead of handing out fish, show people how to fish.

Comment: Intended as a reusable solution, it breaks down problems into two parts. Map for the comparison part and reduce to combine results. May not be necessary in OP's case, but something to think about.